# Transformation in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

> Let $\phi$ be a transformation defined as
> $$\phi:z \mapsto \frac{z}{2-z}$$
> and the circle $C$ is defined as $|z-1|=1$. What's $\phi(C)$.

I know that the circle $C$  has the center $1$ and radius $1$.
I have tried to make the transformation of $3$ points of the circle and it looks like a segment.

Please help me to find the image of the circle $C$ by the transformation $\phi$.

Comment: That is *not* how to describe a transformation named . You have never said what M(z), or M'.  means. If you are trying to say that (z) = z/(2-z), that is what you need to say. After a question like "what's (C)" you need a question mark. Also, in English, a sentence begins with a capital letter, and ends with a period.

Comment: Hint: Any complex transformation of the form f(z) = (az + b) / (cz + d), where a, b, c, d are complex constants with ad - bc ≠ 0 is called a "fractional linear transformation" (FLT). Every FLT takes a circle in the complex plane to a circle or a straight line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w=\displaystyle{z\over 2-z}$ then $z=\displaystyle{2w\over 1+w}$ so $$|z-1| =|{w-1\over w+1}|$$ And thus $$|w-1|=|w+1|$$ when $z \in C$. So $w$ describes imaginary line ($w$ is on the same distance to $-1$ and $1$).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $z = 1 + e^{i\theta} \in C$, with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, hence
$$
z' = \phi(z) = \frac{z}{2-z} = \frac{1+e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} = i\cot(\theta/2),
$$
which corresponds to the imaginary axis.

Comment: The equality $\frac{1+e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} = -e^{i\theta/2}\tan(\theta/2)$ is wrong!! $\phi(C)$ is a straight line, the imaginary axis

Comment: It is still wrong